# Алгоритмическая задача на питоне ("Тимофей ищет место для строительства своего дома")

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, циклы

Всем привет! Совсем недавно начал изучать алгоритмические задачи на питоне и наткнулся на одну задачу, которую никак не могу решить. Прошу вашей помощи(если несложно, можно побольше объяснений):

*Улица, на которой хочет жить Тимофей, имеет длину n, то есть состоит из n одинаковых идущих подряд участков. На каждом участке либо уже построен дом, либо участок пустой. Тимофей ищет место для строительства своего дома. Он очень общителен и не хочет жить далеко от других людей, живущих на этой улице.
Чтобы оптимально выбрать место для строительства, Тимофей хочет для каждого участка знать расстояние до ближайшего пустого участка. (Для пустого участка эта величина будет равна нулю –— расстояние до самого себя).
Ваша задача –— помочь Тимофею посчитать искомые расстояния. Для этого у вас есть карта улицы. Дома в городе Тимофея нумеровались в том порядке, в котором строились, поэтому их номера на карте никак не упорядочены. Пустые участки обозначены нулями.*

**Формат ввода**
*В первой строке дана длина улицы —– n (1 ≤ n ≤ 106). В следующей строке записаны n целых неотрицательных чисел — номера домов и обозначения пустых участков на карте (нули). Гарантируется, что в последовательности есть хотя бы один ноль. Номера домов (положительные числа) уникальны и не превосходят 109.*

**Формат вывода**
*Для каждого из участков выведите расстояние до ближайшего нуля. Числа выводите в одну строку, разделяя их пробелами.*

Пример 1:

**Ввод:**

5

0 1 4 9 0

**Вывод:**

0 1 2 1 0

Пример 2:

**Ввод:**

6

0 7 9 4 8 20

**Вывод:**

0 1 2 3 4 5

**Python | Ограничение времени: 3 сек | Ограничение памяти: 256 мб**

По моим догадкам, нам надо найти расстояние до ближайшего участка слева, потом для ближайшего участка справа, следующий этап: ближайший пустой дом - это или ближайший слева, или ближайший справа.

Код:

```
n = int(input())
numbers = input().split()
for i in range(n):
    if numbers[i] != '0':
        l = 10**6
        for a in range(n):
            if numbers[i - a] == '0':
                if a <= i and l > a:
                    l = a
                if a > i and l > n - a:
                    l = n - a
            numbers[i] = l
print(*numbers)
```

Comment: код добавил,

он работает, но не проходит по времени из-за внутреннего цикла, то есть из задачи 0(n) превращается в квадратичную, а вот как сделать без внутреннего цикла - не понимаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш алгоритм работает за квадрат от числа участков. Вам нужен линейный алгоритм.

Вычислите расстояние до нуля слева. Это легко сделать последовательно. Если в предыдущем участке расстояние было `d`, то в следующем оно будет `d + 1` или ноль. В начало последовательности до первого нуля впишем большие числа.

Расстояние до нуля справа считается также, только надо перевернуть последовательность участков и потом перевернуть результат.

От двух последовательностей берем минимум поэлементно.

Готово:

```
def zero_dists(start, seq):
    d = start
    for n in seq:
        if n == '0':
            d = 0
        else:
            d += 1
        yield d


input()
numbers = input().split()

to_left = zero_dists(len(numbers), numbers)
to_right = reversed(tuple(zero_dists(len(numbers), reversed(numbers))))

print(*map(min, zip(to_left, to_right)))
```

> ```
> $ echo -e "5\n0 1 4 9 0" | python nearest_zeros_2.py 
> 0 1 2 1 0
>
> $ echo -e "6\n0 7 9 4 8 20" | python nearest_zeros_2.py 
> 0 1 2 3 4 5
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Задачку можно решить двумя доп массивами за линейное время.

К примеру, если сначала идти слева направо и сохранять значение ближайшего слева нуля в массиве 1.

Потом идти справа налево и сохранять значение ближайшего справа нуля в массиве 2.

Потом в результирующем массиве брать минимальное значение из первых двух.

Пример кода на C#

```
int[] GetDisctance(int[] input)
{
    var ltor = new int[input.Length];
    var rtol = new int[input.Length];
    var result = new int[input.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        ltor[i] = input[i] == 0 ? 0 : input.Length;
        rtol[i] = input[i] == 0 ? 0 : input.Length;
    }   

    for (int i = 1; i < input.Length; i++)
        ltor[i] = input[i] == 0 ? 0 : ltor[i - 1] + 1;

    for (int i = input.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        rtol[i] = input[i] == 0 ? 0 : rtol[i + 1] + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        result[i] = Math.Min(ltor[i], rtol[i]);

    return result;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно сделать то же самое, но имея только 1 доп массив. А если нам массив на входе можно менять, то и вовсе без доп массивов можно обойтись. Пример

```
int[] GetDisctance(int[] input)
{       
    for(int i=0; i<input.Length; i++)   
        if (input[i] != 0) input[i] = input.Length;
        
    for(int i=1; i<input.Length; i++)
        input[i] = input[i] == 0 ? 0 : input[i-1]+1;

    for (int i = input.Length-2; i > 0; i--)
        input[i] = input[i] == 0 ? 0 : Math.Min(input[i + 1] + 1, input[i]);
        
    return input;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]