# В чем заключается суть алгоритма решения этой задачи

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Есть задача на кодфорсес: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/803/B?locale=ru
Я решил эту задачу за O(n^2) с помощью решения, которое использует индексы нулей и сравнивает каждое.
Там же есть объяснение, как решить эту задачу за О(n). Прочитал, но не могу понять, как и почему получается ответ.
Нашел код:

```
n = int(input())
areas = list(map(int, input().split()))

result = [0 for i in range(n)]

left_zero_index = 0
for i in range(n):
    if areas[i] == 0:
        left_zero_index = i
        break

right_zero_index = 0
for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
    if areas[i] == 0:
        right_zero_index = i
        break

for i in range(left_zero_index, n):
    if areas[i] == 0:
        result[i] = 0
    else:
        result[i] = result[i - 1] + 1

for i in range(right_zero_index - 1, left_zero_index - 1, -1):
    if areas[i] == 0:
        result[i] = 0
    else:
        result[i] = min(result[i], result[i + 1] + 1)

for i in range(left_zero_index - 1, -1, -1):
    result[i] = result[i + 1] + 1

print(*result, sep=" ")
```

Пытаюсь разобраться, но не могу понять, как, все же, приходит ответ. Объясните простым языком как работает этот алгоритм

Comment: Почитайте тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1283936/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первый цикл определяет индекс самого первого нуля.

Второй цикл определяет индекс самого последнего нуля (методом поиска от конца списка).

Третий цикл идёт от первого нуля до конца и проставляет расстояния от предыдущего нуля.
Т.е., допустим, у нас есть список:

```
areas  = [x,x,0,x,x,x,0,x]
```

И изначально в списке расстояний было всё по нулям:

```
result = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

После отрабатывания третьего цикла в списке расстояний будет:

```
areas  = [x,x,0,x,x,x,0,x]
result = [0,0,0,1,2,3,0,1]
```

Как можно заметить, конец (после последнего нуля) уже правильный.

Четвёртый цикл похож на третий, только он идёт справа налево от последнего нуля до первого, но расстояния обновляет только если оно меньше уже записанного в список. Так, после его прохода результат будет содержать:

```
areas  = [x,x,0,x,x,x,0,x]
result = [0,0,0,1,2,1,0,1]
```

- скорректировался отрезок между нулей (его правая часть).

Ну а последний (пятый) цикл дорабатывает левый кончик (от первого нуля влево), заполняя его расстояниями до первого нуля:

```
areas  = [x,x,0,x,x,x,0,x]
result = [2,1,0,1,2,1,0,1]
```

Comment: спасибо! Очень хороший ответ :)

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю питон, но я бы решал так:

1. Создаем новый массив с расстояниями, заполняем его типа int.max - числами, бОльшими, чем количество элементов в массиве
2. Идем по исходному массиву слева направо, пишем в расстояния дистанцию до нулей при таком обходе. То есть в этом проходе мы узнаем расстояние до нуля слева для каждого из элементов массива.
3. Идем справа налево, точно также как в предыдущем обходе считаем расстояние до нуля, но только справа, если оно меньше, чем найденное в предыдущем обходе, обновляем массив расстояний

Как бы код выглядел на шарпе

```
int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7, 0, 9};

int[] distances = new int[array.Length];
for(int i=0; i<distances.Length; i++) distances[i] = int.MaxValue;

// слева направо
int dist = int.MaxValue;
for(int i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
{
    if(array[i] == 0) dist = 0;
    else if (dist != int.MaxValue) dist ++;     
    distances[i] = Math.Min(dist, distances[i]);
}

// справа налево
dist = int.MaxValue;
for (int i = array.Length-1; i >=0; i--)
{
    if (array[i] == 0) dist = 0;
    else if (dist != int.MaxValue) dist++;
    distances[i] = Math.Min(dist, distances[i]);
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", distances));
```

вывод

```
3,2,1,0,1,2,1,0,1,0,1
```

Comment: Ну, собственно, алгоритм в вопросе это и делает.

Comment: @GrAnd там циклов побольше, я потому и не стал разбираться, но он да, должен работать аналогичным образом.

Comment: Там просто циклы разбиты на кусочки. Но, по-сути, если их сложить, то в сумме тоже получается чётко один проход слева направо, и один обратно.